# How to check vulnerabilities in android applications?

Tags: android, security

I am developing an Android Application and I am dealing with very serious data coming from server in this application, so I am in search of any tool which can check vulnerabilities in code so I can make sure that my application is able to protect privacy.
How can I do this please suggest best approach for this.